# Swift 3 Getting audio stream

Tags: javascript, swift3, blob, html5-audio

I am very new to Swift programming, so please pardon me.
What I am trying to do is Im trying to do a voice recording, and below is the method to get the stream from microphone of the iPhone. I am successful at storing the stream to a WAV file inside the device by using this method. I confirmed that the file is OK and is playing fine after the recording

`osErr = ExtAudioFileWrite(destinationFile!, frameCount, inputDataList)`

What i am unsuccessful in doing is capturing the audio stream, pass the stream to the WKWebview as base64 encoded data, converting the data into a Blob then pass the Blob as a source in HTML5 Audio tag using

```
URL.createObjectURL(new Blob( [blob], { type:{"audio/wav"} })
```

The Audio element just throws an Error and does not play the blob. I dont know if what I am getting at the sendAudioBuffer part of my code is the correct data that i should pass.

I am really very thankful for any bits of information. The original code where i got the method is from here

https://gist.github.com/hotpaw2/ba815fc23b5d642705f2b1dedfaf0107

```
func processMicrophoneBuffer( inputDataList: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>, frameCount : UInt32 ) {
    let inputDataPtr = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(inputDataList)
    let mBuffers : AudioBuffer = inputDataPtr[0]
    let count = Int(frameCount)

    let bufferPointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mBuffers.mData)
    if let bptr = bufferPointer {
        let dataArray = bptr.assumingMemoryBound(to: Float.self)
        var sum : Float = 0.0
        var j = self.circInIdx
        let m = self.circBuffSize
        for i in 0..<(count/2) {
            let x = Float(dataArray[i+i  ])   // copy left  channel sample
            let y = Float(dataArray[i+i+1])   // copy right channel sample
            self.circBuffer[j    ] = x
            self.circBuffer[j + 1] = y
            j += 2 ; if j >= m { j = 0 }                // into circular buffer
            sum += x * x + y * y
        }
        self.circInIdx = j              // circular index will always be less than size
        if sum > 0.0 && count > 0 {
            let tmp = 5.0 * (logf(sum / Float(count)) + 20.0)
            let r : Float = 0.2
            audioLevel = r * tmp + (1.0 - r) * audioLevel
        }
    }

    //This will write to a file
    osErr = ExtAudioFileWrite(destinationFile!, frameCount, inputDataList)

    //This will get the audio stream and send to WKWebview to be converted to Blob
    sendAudioBuffer(buffer: Data(bytes: bufferPointer!, count: count))
}
```

Comment: What is `blob` at JavaScript?

Comment: `The Audio element just throws an Error`... Could you please add the error text to your question?

Answer (score 0):

> ... converting the
> data into a Blob then pass the Blob as a source in HTML5 Audio tag
> using
>
> `URL.createObjectURL(new Blob( [blob], { type:{"audio/wav"} })`

You have wrong syntax in the row above. The correct one is:

```
URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob], {type:"audio/wav"}))
```

Also if your `blob` is **really** a `base64` string, you can get rid of `createObjectURL` and set the `src` attribute of your `<source>` in HTML5 Audio tag as a `data-uri` e. g.:

```
document.querySelector('#my_audio source').src = 'data:audio/wav;base64,' + blob;
```

Hope it helps.